Datatables CDN link suddenly stopped working
We have a webapp that uses the datatables CDN and it has suddenly stopped working.
Looking into it, it seems that the CSS and JS files no longer exist.
We are using the following URLS:
https://cdn.datatables.net/w/bs/dt-1.10.18/fc-3.2.5/fh-3.1.4/r-2.2.2/datatables.min.css
https://cdn.datatables.net/w/bs/dt-1.10.18/fc-3.2.5/fh-3.1.4/r-2.2.2/datatables.min.js
Is this a known issue? How can we resolve it quickly so our customers can use it again, then what do we need to do to resolve it properly?
EDIT: It seems that switching https://cdn.datatables.net/w/ to https://cdn.datatables.net/v/ makes it work, but I noticed in our code that at one point we used /v/ and we switched to /w/
What is (was?) the difference between /v/ and /w/? I tried playing in the datatables download builder, but can only get /v/ for the CDN URL. I'm a little scared to change them all to /v/ without knowing what the difference is!

It was me that made the comment on the datatables, thank you for the quick fix!


datatables forum!


The issue with the CDN link not working has been fixed by the excellent team at Datatables.
Regarding the difference between /v/ and /w/, they also answered that here

There is effectively no difference between them. It is an artefact of how the CDN builder used to work - there use to be actual files on the server for each one, and the directory name was one way of handling the massive directories. The newer node based file builder doesn't have that limitation, so the /r, /v, /w (etc) paths all just point at the same node process now.

